# Updating Bias in a neural network

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I would like to know how does the algorithm update the biais in this situation?

[image]

Is it    [image]

or

[image]?

both give me different results. Or is the way i put the bias above wrong? I think it should differents bias per perceptron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **one bias per neuron**, not one global bias. In typical implementations you see one **bias variable** because it is a vector, where i'th dimension is added to i'th neuron.

In the **non standard** network you drew the update rule is actually ... neither! It should be a **sum** of your equations. Note, that if you have bias that is a vector, then using a sum will actually work too, because your partial derivatives that you computed will only affect corresponding dimensions!

Comment: So if i understand the equations are right but it updates the biais in the 1st neurones and 2nd neurones separately? Like b_{2,1} and b_{2,2}?

Comment: Yes you can do it this way. Or you just "vectorise" the equations and do it in one go.